# Replace values for a column if different column is true

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

At this point in my query, my results look roughly like this:

```
id     isCorrect    value
1       0            100
1       0            101
2       1            80
2       0            100
2       0            120
3       1            1
3       1            1
```

And my results need to be like this:

```
id     isCorrect    value
1        0           100.5
1        0           100.5
2        1           80
2        0           80
2        0           80
3        1           1
3        1           1
```

In english, for a given id, I want the value where `isCorrect = 1` to replace the other values for that id. If there is no `isCorrect` row, I want to average them.

As far as I've got is doing a `rank()` function to give me a 1 for rows that I would use, for example:

```
SELECT id, isCorrect, value, rank() over (partition by id order by isCorrect DESC) as correctRank from foo
```

Which will give me

```
id     isCorrect     value    correctRank
1       0             100      1
1       0             101      1
2       1             80       1
2       0             100      3
2       0             120      3
3       1             1        1
3       1             1        1
```

And I've hit a road block as to where to go from there.

Comment: My first thought is to write a  scalar UDF that calculates the value for a given ID.   IF a row exists for the ID where isCorrect=1, do one thing, otherwise do another thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get at the required result using window functions:

```
SELECT id, isCorrect,          
       CASE 
          WHEN MAX(isCorrect) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY isCorrect DESC) = 1
             THEN FIRST_VALUE([value]) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY isCorrect DESC)
          ELSE AVG([value]*1.0) OVER (PARTITION BY id)      
       END AS [value]
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eacec/4)

Comment: Thanks, I'm implementing this now. This is in the context of my original dataset right, not after I do my first window function?

Comment: @Scotch You can apply it directly to the dataset mentioned at the beginning of your post. Note that you need SQL Server 2012+ for this query.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos, you saved me some time. Just implemented it and double checked the data it looks good.

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase this as:

```
select id, isCorrect,
       isnull(max(case when IsCorrect = 1 then value end) over (partition by id),
              avg(value * 1.0) over (partition by id)
             )
from t;
```

I think this code is almost a direct translation of your rules.  If there is a correct value, then use it.  Otherwise, take the average of the values.